# Integrating Angular CLI proxy config in Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I'm bringing over an Angular 6 (CLI) application into Electron, and having problems figuring out how to bring over the proxy config file into the Electron world.

In Angular CLI, specifying the proxy config is pretty straightforward, for instance:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy-config.json
```

The proxy config file looks like this:

```
{
  "context": "/blah",
  "target": "http://blah.com:4848",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": "{"^/blah": ""}
}
```

The problem that I'm having, is understanding how this would correspond into the Electron way of doing things.  I thought maybe the `BrowserWindow.webContents.session.setProxy()` might be a way, but the implementation just doesn't look right, to me -

I feel like this is a more-or-less common problem, and perhaps I'm missing something obvious here.  Any pointers would be hugely appreciated!